# Как сделать коректно Subquery используя Realm

Tags: c#, запрос, realm, подзапрос

**UPD: прошу прощения за дезинформацию, знаний LINQ недостаточно что бы сделать коректный запрос через реалм. Я это немного поздно понял.**

Допустим я имею 2 таблицы: HistoryItem и Quest

HistoryItem внутри имеет поле Quest и другие данные.
В таблице Quest есть поле MaxRepeats.

Что мне нужно получить: мне нужно получить список квестов, который отфильтрован по дате + отфильтрован по количеству записей ЭТОГО ЖЕ КВЕСТА внутри HistoryItem.

В даном случае мне нужно показывать квест только если он был выполнен < MaxRepeats раз.
То есть для каждого из квестов сделать подзапрос, который посчитает количество HistoryItem-ов в которых в поле Quest записан даный квест. Как это сделать?

Пока что у меня просто наработка из рандомного кода т.к. я не понимаю как конкретно эта запись должна выглядеть в принципе:

```
var history = _db.Realm.All<HistoryItem>().Where(a => a.Quest != null).GroupBy(a=>a.Quest);

var tmp = _db.Realm.All<Quest>().Where(a =>
                              a.StartDate < startDayIsLessThan &&
                              a.EndDate > EndDateIsHigherThan);
```

Я нашел синтаксис подзапросов. Например, следующий запрос находит людей, которые имеют больше 3х невакцинированных собак:

```
realm.All<Person>()
    .Filter("SUBQUERY(Dogs, $dog, $dog.Vaccinated == false).@count > 3")
```

Comment: `Quests.Where(q => q.MaxRepeats > HistoryItems.Count(h => h.Quest == q))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было сделать обратный линк внутри `Quest` от `HistoryItem` (раньше был только прямой с HistoryItem в Quest)

```
public class Quest : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MaxRepeats { get; set; } 

    [Backlink(nameof(HistoryItem.Quest))]
    public IQueryable<HistoryItem> HistoryItems{ get; }       
}

public class HistoryItem : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTimeOffset DoneTime { get; set; }

    public Quest Quest { get; set; }
}
```

А дальше использовать запрос с фильтром:

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Filter("HistoryItems.@count <= MaxRepeats");
```

Ну и в моем случае еще нужно было игнорировать случаи когда максРипитс равен 0:

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Filter("MaxRepeats == 0 OR HistoryItems.@count <= MaxRepeats");
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы двигались в правильном направлении.

```
    var histCount = _db.Realm.All<HistoryItem>()
        .GroupBy(h => h.Quest)
        .Select(gr => new {Q = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count()});

    var result = _db.Realm.All<Quest>()
        // сокращаем коллекцию до join
        .Where(q => q.StartDate > start && q.EndDate < end) // todo: перепроверить условие 
        // join с группированной коллекцией элементов истории
        .Join(histCount,
            quest => quest.Id,
            hCount => hCount.Q,
            (quest, hCount) => new {Quest = quest, HCount = hCount.Count})
        // фильтрация по условиям кол-ва элементов
        .Where(it => it.HCount < it.Quest.MaxRepeats)
        // выборка результата
        .Select(it => it.Quest)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и выделенное время. До меня только что дошло как гуглить и оказалось что знаний LINQ недостаточно что бы сделать правильный подзапрос через realm =(